# App strucks when moving from SplashScreenActivity (full screen) to MainActivity (Non full screen)

Tags: android, fullscreen, splash-screen

I Have a `SplashScreenActivity` which is full screen and it moves to `MainActivity` after 3 seconds.

`styles.xml` for `SplashScreenActivity` :

```
<!-- Theme for Splash with no Action bar full screen -->
<style name="splash_screen" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

`styles.xml` for `MainActivity` :

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
    <item name="vpiCirclePageIndicatorStyle">@style/CustomCirclePageIndicator</item>
</style>
```

When app moves from `SplashScreenActivity` to `MainActivity` as it is moving from full-screen to non full-screen, `Layout` appears and then moves a bit downwards.

I have already used

```
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
    getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN);
    getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
```

and also

```
android:paddingTop="25dp"
```

but no luck.

Can anyone provide a solution to this problem ??

EDIT :

`SplashScreenActivity` :

```
    public class SplashScreenActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.splash);
        EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
        callWeatherService(this);
        delayedTask();
    }

    private void delayedTask() {
        Runnable splashRunnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
            }
        };
        new Handler().postDelayed(splashRunnable, Numerics.THREE_THOUSAND);
    }

    public void onEventMainThread(WeatherModel weather) {
        if (weather != null) {
            Preferences.getIns().saveWeather(weather);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
    }
}
```

`MainActivity` :

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener, ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener, ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener, View.OnClickListener {

    private Toolbar mToolbar;

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;

    private FragmentManager mFragmentManager;

    private FragmentTransaction mFragmentTransaction;

    private ExpandableListAdapter mExpandableListAdapter;

    private ExpandableListView mExpandableListView;

    private List<String> mGroupList;

    private Map<String, List<String>> mChildList;

    private TextView toolbarTitle;

    private ImageView weatherImg;

    private int selectedItem = -1;

    private int lastExpandedPosition = -1;

    private TextView userEmailTxt;

    private TextView userNameTxt;

    private ImageView editBtn;

    public int getSelectedItem() {
        return selectedItem;
    }

    public void setSelectedItem(int selectedItem) {
        this.selectedItem = selectedItem;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
    getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN);
    getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        toolbarTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);
        weatherImg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.weather_img);
        weatherImg.setOnClickListener(this);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, mDrawerLayout, mToolbar,
                R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(view);
                if (lastExpandedPosition != -1
                        ) {
                    mExpandableListView.collapseGroup(lastExpandedPosition);
                }
                lastExpandedPosition = -1;
            }
        };

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();

        setDrawerList();
        setUserDetails();
        setFonts();
        loadFragment(0);

    }

    private void setUserDetails() {
        userNameTxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.user_name);
        userEmailTxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.user_email);
        editBtn = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.edit_btn);
        editBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
        userNameTxt.setText(R.string.lokes);
        userEmailTxt.setText(R.string.lokesh_mail);

    }

    private void setDrawerList() {
        mExpandableListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expandable_lst);
        mExpandableListView.setGroupIndicator(null);

        prepareListData();

        mExpandableListAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, mGroupList, mChildList);

        // setting list adapter
        mExpandableListView.setAdapter(mExpandableListAdapter);
        mExpandableListView.setOnGroupClickListener(this);
        mExpandableListView.setOnChildClickListener(this);
        mExpandableListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(this);
    }

    private void prepareListData() {
        // data to expandable list view
    }

    private void loadFragment(int position) {
        String title = null;
        invalidateOptionsMenu();
        Fragment fragment = null;
        if (position == getSelectedItem()) {
            // Already selected fragment is being displayed
        } else {
            switch (position) {
                case Numerics.ZERO:
                    fragment = new DashBoardFragment();
                    title = getString(R.string.dashboard);
                    break;
                case Numerics.ONE:
                    break;
                case Numerics.TWO:
                    break;
                case Numerics.THREE:
                    break;
                case Numerics.FOUR:
                    break;
                case Numerics.FIVE:
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            if (fragment != null) {
                showFragment(fragment, title);
            }
            setSelectedItem(position);
        }
    }

    public void showFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        if (fragment != null) {
            String backStateName = fragment.getClass().getName();
            mFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            mFragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            mFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.dashboard_container, fragment);
            mFragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(backStateName);
            mFragmentTransaction.commit();
            setActionBarTitle(title);
            if (backStateName == DashBoardFragment.class.getSimpleName()) {
                clearBackStack();
            }
        }
    }

    public void setActionBarTitle(String title) {
        if (toolbarTitle != null && !TextUtils.isEmpty(title)) {
            toolbarTitle.setText(title);
        }
    }

    private void clearBackStack() {
        mFragmentManager.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
        setSelectedItem(Numerics.ZERO);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.LEFT)) {
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
        } else {
            int backStackCount = mFragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount();
            if (backStackCount > 0) {
                popFragments(backStackCount);
            } else {
                finish();
            }
        }
    }

    private void popFragments(int backStackCount) {
        String fragmentTag = mFragmentManager.getBackStackEntryAt(
                backStackCount - 1).getName();
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(fragmentTag)) {
            Fragment currentFragment = mFragmentManager
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.dashboard_container);
            if (currentFragment != null && currentFragment instanceof DashBoardFragment) {
                finish();
            } else {
                mFragmentManager.popBackStack();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, long id) {
        if (mChildList.get(mGroupList.get(groupPosition))
                .isEmpty() && mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.LEFT)) {
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
        v.setBackgroundResource(R.color.exp_lst_selected);
        if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.LEFT)) {
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
        }
        openChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
        return false;
    }

    private void openChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        //handle on open child
    }

    @Override
    public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
        if (lastExpandedPosition != -1
                && groupPosition != lastExpandedPosition) {
            mExpandableListView.collapseGroup(lastExpandedPosition);
        }
        lastExpandedPosition = groupPosition;
    }

    private void setFonts() {
        Fonts.getInstance(this).setMediumFont(toolbarTitle);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        ToastFactory.showToast(R.string.app_name);
    }
}
```

EDIT 2:

```
AndroidManifest.xml :

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.myapp">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:name=".activities.App"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity
        android:name=".activities.MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"/>

    <activity android:name=".activities.SplashScreenActivity"
        android:theme="@style/splash_screen">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service android:name=".services.rest.RestService" />
</application>
```

Comment: Any errors in LogCat?

Comment: no, just UI moves downwards and fits the screen, thats all. I think my problem has nothing to do with Log

Comment: getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
    getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN);
    getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS); 
are those lines ABOVE setContentView ????

Comment: SplashScreenActivity  java code?

Comment: @LuciusHipan, yes I have tried giving them both before and after `setContentView`

Comment: give relevant java codes of both activities please

Comment: @LuciusHipan, added java code for splash and main activity. please have a look

Comment: can you also post your manifest xml..

Comment: your problem is.. supposed to be your main activity is not full screen but it appears full screen, right?

Comment: @ville101 : no, main activity is not full screen, it is appearing ok, but when transition from splash to main app UI stucks and adjusts as it is moving from full screen to non-full screen

Comment: @LuciusHipan, added manifest code in EDIT 2

Comment: Try some animations like fade in, fade out..

Comment: there are too many lines of code that do nothing

Answer (score 0):

You have too many lines that do nothing. Here is my example, that works as expected:
In manifest DO NOTHING :

```
 <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".SplashActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
</application>
```

In my styles.xml DO NOTHING, just extend from correct Theme

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
           //nothing to do with fullscreen it all extended
</style>
```

Splash Activity just `LinearLayout` .
Main Activity no overriding window at all, you've already extended the right Theme.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.main_page_toolbar_parent);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(null);
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.action_settings, R.string.app_name) {

            /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state. */
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(view);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }

            /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container_frame, new MainActivityFragment()).commit();
    }
}
```

It works for me in all the Applications I've needed Splash.

Comment: I need full screen for splash

Comment: It will be full screen